# Uk Visit visa for my parents from India got refused due to no transactions in bank account, despite sufficient funds

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

We applied for a UK visit visa for my parents and it was refused, stating that "there are no transactions from your account, so how you are fixing your expenditure in your home country is not clear so I am not satisfied".

Actually we have given proof by satisfied maximum funds in their account, and we stated that income was 200,000 and monthly expenses are 10,000. But actually those monthly expenses are maintenance through rental money, because they have houses in their names and they are rented out. The rental income is paid in cash, not through banks. How can we show them these details as they can handle the monthly maintenance without drawing money from their account? Actually we have provided house details also, like property details as a tie. So we stated that they have another daughter in India, and we also provided it as a family tie, but still they are saying no satisfactory proof for that.

We want to apply again for a visa, so what is the process, and how do we declare these details?
How to prove that my parents have another daughter in home country?she was married and not dependent on my parents.but I have my grand father he is with my parents some times and sometimes with my uncle..so we r confused what to provide as a proof of family ties

Comment: You'll get more incisive comments and answers if you add a copy of the visa refusal letter into your question. First, obscure personal details such as name, address, passport number, etc. from the letter. Then use the "Edit" button below the question text, then the "Moon and Mountains" button just above the edit/text entry field. You can then drag and drop the image of the letter into the answer text itself.

Comment: By providing certified business accounts which show the property income and expenditure? Otherwise if it is all "cash in hand" there is nothing you can prove. Also "we stated that they have another daughter in India" but what proof did you give?

Comment: Note that "we stated" isn't proof. A less honest person could have just told a story.

Comment: Start having the rental income paid into their bank account and expenses paid out of it. Wait *at least* 6 months before they reapply, making sure to provide their latest tax return with the supporting papers. Property isn’t much of a tie - rental income would continue and could be relatively easily accessed from anywhere.

Comment: Regular deposits of cash could show a regular source of income; if the money isn't going in the bank there's no proof of its existence. However it sounds like there are multiple issues: both questions over your income and over your ties to your home country, so you'd have to tackle both separately.

Comment: Family ties means more than just the existence of close relatives. Some kind of compelling reason to return due to the tie is typically needed. A daughter who is living independently and an elderly parent who stays from time to time isn’t going to count, ongoing care responsibilities and / or financial support (of the kind requiring your patrnts’ presence in their home country) is what’s needed